# Xamarin (Visual Studio 2019) Xaml Previewer Not working on Windows or Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have created my first Xamarin Project, simply using the template created by Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. When I try to open the previewer for the XAML for the IOS I get this error:

Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPOVH.png
The error code:
    `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred...`
    https://pastebin.com/4kwiGW2U

This also occurs on my Macbook with the same setup.

Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExzXa.png
The error code:
    `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred...`
    https://pastebin.com/RvdPdKUw

I am using visual studio version 16.6.0

This is my first Stack overflow post so I may not be providing all the necessary info, so please just comment and ask if you need any more info to properly answer the question :)

**Thanks everyone!**

P.S I am on Windows 10 with an AMD Ryzen 7 1700 and the Macbook is a Macbook Pro (2016), dual-core intel core i7

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio on Windows, you must be paired to a Mac to use this mode .

Comment: Ever since Hot Reload was introduced the previewer has been moved out of its focus, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload If you insist using the previewer, check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/?pivots=windows#troubleshooting

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I did do that, but despite this, I get the error even on my MacBook...

Comment: @LexLi I just looked up the hot reload stuff and it looks like it'll work :) I'll have to test it but thanks so much for the help! I've never posted on stack overflow but definitely didn't expect a response this quickly.

Comment: Keep asking questions with clear descriptions and all necessary details, and you will receive this kind of help quite often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for anyone wondering:

Don't use the previewer, it is redundant since the implementation of Hot Reload. :)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload

Thanks, @Lex Li for the help!

Edit:

I've actually found a fix for this entirely. You can revert the version of the Xamarin.Forms NuGet Package to version 4.5.0.356. :)

Goodluck everyone!

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people :)

Comment: Yep just did that, actually found another fix entirely so that's the ideal solution I think.